# Why is $\langle x-P(x),m\rangle=0$?

Tags: calculus, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $M\le H$ be a subspace of it.

Let $P:H\rightarrow M$ be the orthogonal projection $H$ onto $M$.

We'll take $x\in H$, and $m \in M$.

By the definition I know $d(x,M)=d(x,P(x))$. (where $d$ is the induced metric).

Is it true that $\langle x-P(x),m\rangle=0$? And why?

Comment: Isn't it part of the definition of orthogonal projection?

Comment: Perhaps I know an equivalent Definition, But I can't see the equivalence.  Definition: $P:H→M$ is the orthogonal projection H onto M, if $d(x,M)=d(x,P(x))$

Comment: OK. Do you know that, for all $m\in M$, if $m\ne P(x)$, then $d(x,m)>d(x,P(x))$?

Comment: Indeed (I needed at least 15 characters for commenting, so this is it).

Comment: If it's not zero, then multiplying $m$ by a scalar $e^{i\theta}$, we may assume that $\langle x-P(x), e^{i\theta}m\rangle = -c < 0$. Then if you shift thus: $x-P(x) \mapsto x-P(x) + te^{i\theta}m$ for a small enough $t$, you'll see that this is closer and hence get a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

It is true. It follows the condition of optimality for optimization problem.

Proof:

Consider  $F(y) = \left<x-y,x-y\right>$. The problem
$$
F(y)\to\min,\ y\in M
$$
has a unique solution, $P(x)$. Since $F$ is a convex function and $M$ is a convex set, then the following holds:
$$
\left<\nabla F(P(x)), v -  P(x)\right> \geqslant 0\text{ for all }v\in M.
$$
Obviously, $\nabla F(y) = 2(y-x)$. Then for any $m\in M$ we can select $v = P(x)+m$ ($v\in M$ because $M$ is subsapce), then
$$
\left<P(x)-x,m \right> \geqslant 0.
$$ 
Selecting now $v = P(x)-m$, we obtain
$$
\left<P(x)-x,m \right> \leqslant 0.
$$
Hence, $\left<P(x)-x,m \right> =0$ for any $m\in M$.